# Router A inaccesible from pc connected to router b: why?

Tags: networking

follow my network configuration
[image]

```
Router Vpn B, DD-WRT, Lan config : 
  ip: `192.168.1.1`
  Netmask: `255.255.255.0` 
  Gateway: `192.168.1.254`
  Configured as gateway PPTP connected to a foreign server

Router main gateway, main internet gateway: 
  ip: `192.168.1.254`
  Netmask: `255.255.255.0`
```

If i try to connect from Pc3 or Pc4 to router B (192.168.1.1) .. i can't!

Instead, if i try to connect from Pc1 or Pc2 .. i can!

My question is: why Pc3 and Pc4 can't connect to Router B web interface ?

Any ideas ?

**EDIT: Also if ping from Pc3 or Pc4 to router vpn b .. it doesn't respond.** Pc3 / Pc4 has ip address of same class of network (192.168.1.X), and gateway : 192.168.1.254 (router gatway internet) or, also if i try, gateway 192.168.1.1 (but not respond).

Comment: Do your PCs directly connect to each router?

Comment: Yes: Pc1 and Pc2 directly to router B.  Pc3 and Pc4 to router Gateway (i called router gatway only because is the internet gateway)

Comment: Check your router B configuration. Maybe it doesn't allow access from outside

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, from your diagram and question, it's router B that's inaccessible from PCs connected to router A; but your question title has this backwards.  I'm going to assume the title is wrong.

There are all sorts of possible other reasons, but one that comes straight to mind is that many of these devices don't allow connections to their configuration interface from the "outside" NIC, which in this case is the one facing router A and PCs 3 and 4.

This is configurable in most such devices, but without details about what router B is, it is impossible to advise you (and might well be even with details).  Check the manual for router B about de-restricting connections to the configuration interface.

**Edit**: many such devices also do not allow ICMP echo-request (ping) on the outside NIC, either.  As far as router B is concerned, everything outside it is the internet, and hostile.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Router B is not allowing configuration access from what it considers the WAN interface but does allow access via its LAN interface.